# Problem with accessing the views from exception within asyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

[image]

I am having a problem which is I think that I can't access th,e ListView from the asyncTask

Actually, I really don't know the real problem here
Let me show you what is happening

I have an activity which is executing AsyncTask and creates `HttpURLConnection`. Sometimes I get an exception (`ProtocolException`) because the stream un-expectedly ends.
So, I created a handler for this exception that calls a function or a method inside the class of the activity to display a message to the user

Here is a picture so you understand what is my project.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJGqp.png)

the problem here whenever the exception is thrown, the same function/method that I use to add the text to the listView is called, but after it called the listView disappear, but when I minimize the soft keyboard manually the everything becomes fine.

the structure of my class is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        addMessageToListView()//works fin here
    }
    protected void addMessage(String message, int userMessage, ListView listView) // the function
    {
        try
        {
            messages.add(new Message(message,userMessage));
            MessagesAdapter messagesAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(messages, getBaseContext());
            messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(messagesAdapter);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

        }
    }
     private class HttpPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        ...
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            try
            {
                addMessageToListView()//works fin here
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

            }
        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i <= 0; ++i)
            {
                result = this.invokePost(params[i], this.postData);
            }
            return result;
        }
        private String invokePost(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams)// called from doInBackground
        {
        try
            {
                addMessageToListView()//works fin here
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                addMessageToListView()//not orking here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to explain more actually.

Comment: May be listview is still there but because of keyboard ,your are not able to see text which is below.

Comment: I don't think so, because even the text above the keyboard disappear, and when I let the keyboard down and the problem happens the same, I need to show the keyboard, so I think it is because it is refreshing the content for resizing

Answer (score 0):

You can change Views only in mainthread of your app. The doInBackground doesn't run in mainthread of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding:

```
new Thread() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                addMessageToListView()//not orking here
                            }
                        });
                        super.run();
                    }
                }.start();
```

Editing the previous code in my question:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        addMessageToListView()//works fin here
    }
    protected void addMessage(String message, int userMessage, ListView listView) // the function
    {
        try
        {
            messages.add(new Message(message,userMessage));
            MessagesAdapter messagesAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(messages, getBaseContext());
            messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(messagesAdapter);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

        }
    }
     private class HttpPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        ...
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            try
            {
                addMessageToListView()//works fin here
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

            }
        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i <= 0; ++i)
            {
                result = this.invokePost(params[i], this.postData);
            }
            return result;
        }
        private String invokePost(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams)// called from doInBackground
        {
        try
            {
                addMessageToListView()//works fin here
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                new Thread() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                addMessageToListView()//not orking here
                            }
                        });
                        super.run();
                    }
                }.start();

            }
        }
    }
}
```